# PHP run curl with exec not working

Tags: php, linux, curl, exec

When I run my curl command in the command prompt it works fine, but
when I run it in my PHP file using exec it doesn't execute, can
somebody tell me why that is ? In the error log file it says,

"'curl' is not recognized as an internal or external command "

I checked my php configurations, curl is enabled there.

Comment: Thank you for the quick responses, but as I said curl is recognized when I typed it in command prompt, but when I try executing it in PHP file using exec it doesn't work, I already added curl.exe path to my environment variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you write I guess you use windows so:

1. It can be executed from cmd.exe when you are exact directory where curl is installed but as other suggested if you want to have access to it globally you will need add curl.exe to your PATH variable.
2. Despite this, there is better way to use CURL in PHP than using exec. A whole module is available. You can go to [this site](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) and check it. To install php curl on windows you'll probably need to install an extension.

Notice from manual:

> In order to enable this module on a Windows environment, libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll must be present in your PATH. You don't need libcurl.dll from the cURL site.

Check [this site](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/php/install.html) as well.

Good luck

Comment: Thanks for your help, it worked after moving the files u specified above to the Windows/System32

Comment: if you add them to this directory then they are globally available puting them on PATH env should work as well

Answer (score 0):

you probably do not have the path set. Set the environment path (add curl executable bin to the path) and then restart the command prompt. it should work

Answer (score 0):

In your PHP script,

- either use the full path to `curl` (which you can find out using `which curl` on the commandline),
- or use the [cURL API that is available in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php). This is the preferred method because not all hosts have `exec` enabled for PHP.